# Error in adding tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using STS with tomcat 6 but I am not able to add tomcat 7. I have tried to remove all servers and add them again but still the problem persists. It says

**cannot create a server of the selected type**

What can be the cause?